# Create multiple timelines in one shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, vis.js-timeline

I've created a similar question but this one is more complex. For a minimal example, let's say I create this app

```
library(timevis)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

df_original <- data.frame(id =c(1),
                 text1 =c('d'),
                 text2 =c('h'),
                 text3 =c('l'),
                 time1 =c('2019-01-08 20:30:00'),
                 time2 =c('2019-01-08 20:40:00'),
                 time3 =c('2019-01-08 20:50:00'),
                 time4 =c('2019-01-08 21:00:00'),
                 time5 =c('2019-01-08 20:48:00'),
                 time6 =c('2019-01-08 20:34:00'))

df_original$time1 <- as.POSIXct(df_original$time1,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df_original$time2 <- as.POSIXct(df_original$time2,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df_original$time3 <- as.POSIXct(df_original$time3,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df_original$time4 <- as.POSIXct(df_original$time4,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df_original$time5 <- as.POSIXct(df_original$time5,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df_original$time6 <- as.POSIXct(df_original$time6,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

##############################################UI

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "")

#Sidebar
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  #DF type menu
  selectInput(inputId = 'df',
              label = 'Type of DF',
              choices = c('DF1', 'DF2', 'DF3', 'DF4'),
              selected = 'DF1')
)

#Text Row
frow1 <- fluidRow(box(width = 12,
                      splitLayout(
                        textOutput("text1"),
                        textOutput("text2"),
                        textOutput('text3'))
))

#Timeline Row
frow2 <- fluidRow(box(timevisOutput("timeline"),width = NULL
                      ))

#Body function
body <- dashboardBody(frow1,frow2)

#UI aggregation
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = 'black')

###############################Server
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  #Converting Df original to timevis ready data
  
  Summary <- reactive({
    #Transposing
    agg <- data.frame(r1=names(df_original), t(df_original))
    colnames(agg) <- c("content","start")
    #Removing text columns
    agg <- agg[-c(1,2,3,4),]
    #Adding group id
    agg$group <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2)
    #Rearranging columns
    agg <- agg[c(2,3,1)]
    agg$start <- ymd_hms(agg$start)
    agg$content <- as.factor(agg$content)
    #Adding section column to tell which timestamp belong to which DF when switching
    agg$section <- c(4,2,3,4,3,2)
    agg$section <- as.numeric(agg$section)
    return(data.frame(agg))
  })
  
  
  #if condition for DF1,DF2,DF3,DF4
  
  df <-reactive({
    if (input$df == "DF2") {
      df <- Summary()[which(Summary()$section == 2),]
    }
    else if (input$df == "DF3") {
      df <- Summary()[Summary()$section == 3,]
    }
    else if (input$df == "DF4") {
      df <- Summary()[(Summary()$section == 4),]
    }
    else {
      df <- Summary()
    }
    return(df)
  })
  
  output$timeline <- renderTimevis(
    timevis(
      df(),
      groups = data.frame(id = 1:4, content = c('Group1','Group2','Group3','Group4'))
      ,options = list( showCurrentTime = FALSE)
    )
  )
  
  output$text1 <- renderText({paste("Text1:", df_original$text1)})
  output$text2 <- renderText({paste("Text2:", df_original$text2)})
  output$text3 <- renderText({paste("Text3:", df_original$text3)})

}

#####################################Execution
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here, I have 3 text columns and 3 timestamps. I have to display text as outputs ad then display a timeline based on the timestamps. The timestamps need to be divided into groups. Here's the tricky part. I also have to change my timeline with respect to user's input - whether the user wants to see certain groups of timestamps, or all the timestamps. This group is different from the earlier group dividing the timeline. The output comes out like this
[image: Basic Output]

Here, when you change the type of df, it will change the timeline according to section defined on server code.

How do I create a similar app for dataframe like this

```
df <- data.frame(id =c(1,2,3,4),
                 text1 =c('a','b','c','d'),
                 text2 =c('e','f','g','h'),
                 text3 =c('i','j','k','l'),
                 time1 =c('2019-01-08 20:00:00','2019-01-08 20:35:00','2019-01-08 21:10:00','2019-01-08 20:30:00'),
                 time2 =c('2019-01-08 20:10:00','2019-01-08 20:50:00','2019-01-08 21:00:00','2019-01-08 20:40:00'),
                 time3 =c('2019-01-08 21:20:00','2019-01-08 20:40:00','2019-01-08 21:20:00','2019-01-08 20:50:00'),
                 time4 =c('2019-01-08 22:30:00','2019-01-08 20:45:00','2019-01-08 21:30:00','2019-01-08 21:00:00'),
                 time1 =c('2019-01-08 20:23:00','2019-01-08 20:55:00','2019-01-08 21:23:00','2019-01-08 20:48:00'),
                 time1 =c('2019-01-08 20:16:00','2019-01-08 20:48:00','2019-01-08 21:16:00','2019-01-08 20:34:00'))
```

such that my output comes as multiple timelines - one for each ID - in a single shiny app. The output will come out like this [image: Desired Output]